# Steps in a proof from Spectral Graph Theory by Fan Chung

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, spectral-graph-theory

On page 15 of Spectral Graph Theory by Fan Chung, http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/research/cb/ch1.pdf, before eq (1.14) is the step,

$\displaystyle || \sum_{i\neq 0} (1-\lambda_i)^s a_i \phi_i T^{\frac{1}{2}} || \leq (1-\lambda')^s\frac{\max_x \sqrt{d_x}}{\min_y \sqrt{d_y}}$.

Popping out the eigenvalue term is obvious and I've seen this inequality proven different ways, eg. http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/rraj/Courses/7880/S12/Lectures/lec7_RandomWalks2.pdf, but would like to know why the max/min part should be obvious directly from the line above. Maybe I'm tired, but it just isn't jumping out at me.

To clarify, this relates to bounding the distance between the distribution resulting from a random walk and the stationary distribution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe she is estimating as: $$ || \sum_i a_i \phi_i T^{\frac{1}{2}} || \leq ||  T^{\frac{1}{2}} || \cdot || \sum_{i \neq 0} a_i \phi_i || \\ \leq ||  T^{\frac{1}{2}} || \cdot || \sum_{i} a_i \phi_i || \leq ||  T^{\frac{1}{2}} || \cdot || f T^{-\frac{1}{2}} || \\ \leq  || T^{\frac{1}{2}} || \cdot || T^{-\frac{1}{2} } || \cdot || f|| \leq \frac{\max_x \sqrt{d_x}}{ \min_y \sqrt{d_y} }$$

Comment: I also thought of this earlier, but in this case, $||f||\geq 1$, since f is a probability distribution. Also, it seems unclear that adding in the $i=0$ term would necessarily weaken the bound.

Comment: edit: $||f|| \leq 1$, so ignore that part.

Comment: $ || f || \leq 1 $ because $ f $ is positive and $ \langle f, 1 \rangle = 1 $. Since $ \phi_i $ is an orthonormal basis, we have $ || f || = \sum_i a_i^2 $, so it is clear how the $ a_0 $ term affects the bound.

Comment: Yea, the part about $||f|| \geq 1$ I realized was plain stupid on my part. However, it's still not clear to me that we know how the $a_0$ term affects the bound. Why is it not possible that $|| \sum_i a_i \phi_i || \leq || \sum_{i\neq 0} a_i \phi_i || $? This is the part that isn't clear to me.

Comment: It is because the $ a_i $ are real, and the $ \phi_i $ are an orthonormal basis. So, $ || \sum_{i \neq 0} a_i \phi_i || = a_1^2 + a_2^2 \cdots $ and $ || \sum_{i} a_i \phi_i || = a_0^2 + a_1^2 + a_2^2 \cdots $. Here $ a_0^2 > 0 $, so always $  || \sum_i a_i \phi_i || \geq || \sum_{i\neq 0} a_i \phi_i || $.

Comment: Yes, of course that's right, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!